# How can we lock a folder in iPad programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, locking, directory

I created a Folder in my Ipad. Is there any possibilities to lock that folder programmatically through my application?

Answer (score 0):

the folder you have created will be only accesible to your app "sandbox", if you are using file sharing, the user cannot delete your folder or its contents, only what is on the root level

> \Documents

please clarify if you want to lock it for file sharing or what purpose?
good luck!

Comment: :I created a folder manually by dragging and dropping the apps into that folder in iPad. My requirement is that I want to secure that folder from other users.All this password secure should done through my application.

Comment: ah I see, so is not part of your app, in this case Apple doesnt let you have programatically access to resources outside your app, in this case the folders?, you could have an app that manages the other apps?, are this your apps?, another way would be to go to settings and disable with password the apps you want disabled

Answer (score 0):

No. Your app does not have access to, or control over, home screen folders on a non-jailbroken device.